# Why is there no `map` method on `Iterable`

Tags: java

`Iterable` has a `forEach` default method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Why does it not have a `map` method?

For example, `Map` has a `map` method.

Comment: Probably because `map` can be defined in terms of a `foreach`, but not necessarily vise versa, and the less methods an interface requires, the better.

Comment: You might be interested in Guava's `Iterables.transform()`.

Comment: `Map` doesn't have a `map` method, and it's not `Iterable`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about "why is this language/framework feature designed this way?" can only be definitively answered by the language/framework designers..

Comment: Could you guys point me to the Map.map method you talking about?

Comment: @TimBüthe Uhh, good point. I should go look up what I was smoking when I asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

Following excerpt from the [Stream java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) tries to explain :

> Collections and streams, while bearing some superficial similarities, have different goals. Collections are primarily concerned with the efficient management of, and access to, their elements. By contrast, streams do not provide a means to directly access or manipulate their elements, and are instead concerned with declaratively describing their source and the computational operations which will be performed in aggregate on that source.

In essence, Iterable deals with access and traversal while Streams are more involved with transformations & computations.

Comment: Nothing in your quote addresses Iterables.

Comment: Map has map though. Seems like an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @jm1234567890 wut

Comment: @shmosel Collections are Iterables.  They’re not the only Iterables, but they represent most Iterables.

Comment: @jm1234567890 based on [Map's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), Map doesn't have a 'map' operation. It's a bit of a read but [JSR 335](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335) explains some of the reasoning behind using a new Stream interface & not mixing it with Iterables.

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion, the reason seems to be if there was a `map` method on `Iterable` it would have to return an `Iterable`. This would be odd for Collections.

For example, `List.map` would have to return an `Iterable`

This is not case for `Map.map`.